# Hello Django renames the model of my app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-apps

After having a typo and mistyped **pricing** as ***prising***

I've removed the app, deleted the tables in the database then made the new app copied the `models.py` from the  old app, **I did a backup**,  then  the error persist here is the admin-panel[image]

here is the models.py

```
class PriceList(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("ценоразпис")
        verbose_name_plural = _("ценоразписи")


    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=300, verbose_name="наименование")
    description = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=300, verbose_name="Описание")

    def show_name(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
    def show_description(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.description)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

class PriceListItem(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("елемент от ценоразпис")
        verbose_name_plural = _("елементи от ценоразпис")
        ordering = ['id']

    price_list = models.ForeignKey(PriceList, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="ценоразпис", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title_bg = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200, verbose_name="наименование BG")
    description_bg = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200, verbose_name="Описание BG")
    title_en = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200, verbose_name="наименование EN")
    description_en = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200, verbose_name="Описание EN")
    price_bg = models.DecimalField(blank=False, null=False, decimal_places=PRICE_DECIMAL_PLACES, max_digits=PRICE_DECIMAL_DIGITS, verbose_name="BGN")
    price_en = models.DecimalField(blank=False, null=False, decimal_places=PRICE_DECIMAL_PLACES, max_digits=PRICE_DECIMAL_DIGITS, verbose_name="EUR")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)
```

and the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from pricing.models import PriceList, PriceListItem


class PriceListItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PriceListItem


class PriceListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = PriceList
    inlines = [PriceListItemInline, ]
    list_display = ('name', 'description')




admin.site.register(PriceList , PriceListAdmin)
```

Comment: did you run : python manage.py makemigrations then python manage.py migrate ?

Comment: yeah a couple of times :)

Comment: Try deleting your migrations folder and running the two commands again

Comment: I've tried, i've deleted the migrations from the file and deleted the migrations from the database, dropped the tables and did it again it didn't work

Comment: try running the command this way : python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name !
Is it even detecting your new models when you run this ?

Comment: when i run the migrations there is ` options={
                'verbose_name_plural': 'prising',
                'verbose_name': 'prising',
            },` in the 0001.initial.py

Comment: Change `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` and migrate

Comment: Allright Job Done :) ty guys for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command after you've deleted your migrations folder:

### Python manage.py squashmigrations

Then re-run your migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py migrate
```

If this doesn't work then delete your db if its Sqlite and then re-run your migrations.

Comment: Thanks buddy i should've messed up something :)

Comment: @KostadinSlavov, Anytime brother :-)

Answer (score 0):

Rerun the migrations for that app again.

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app>

python manage.py migrate
```

Will fix the issue.